# Changing file names inside the shapefile.zip file obtained from a WFS

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, openlayers, wfs

I am using the following format to download a shapefile from a GeoServer WFS.

```
http://some.domain.com/geoserver/WFC/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=WFC:someLayerName&maxfeatures=5000&outputformat=SHAPE-ZIP
```

I receive a shapefile named WFC:someLayerName.zip and the different files inside that zip folder are named as someLayerNamePolygon.shp or someLayerNamePolygon.cst etc. 
I was wondering if there is a way to change the name of files INSIDE the zip folder? I am aware that the name of the actual shapefile.zip can be changed but that does not affect the name of the files inside the zip folder.

Comment: Are you looking to do this using code? If so what have you tried? Need some more information.

Comment: Currently, no I am not using code. I am not sure what other information would you need. I was hoping to know if there is a URL field that I can use to change the name of the files. Skimming through the documentation didn't reveal a lot. For example, I can add "&format_option=filename:<zipfile>" and I can change the name of the zip file that I receive. I was wondering if there is a field that I can add to change the filenames inside the zip file.

Comment: A quick scan of Python's `zipfile` library didn't reveal any way of changing the name of a file within a ZIP archive file. A third-party program (WinZip, 7-Zip, etc.) may be able to do it, but it will be interactive, and the user would have to rename each component file of the shapefile (DBF, PRJ, SHP, SHX, etc.).

Comment: I don't think you can change the names of the content within the zipped shapefile, as part of the WFS request that you are using to generate the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoServer does not offer option for the user to select the filenames inside shape-zip with additional GetFeature parameters. You have an option to use some single file outputformat like GML or GeoJSON and send GetFeature with curl or wget

```
curl -o foo.gml "http://some.domain.com/geoserver/WFC/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=WFC:someLayerName&maxfeatures=5000&outputformat=GML"
```

Alternatively you can download shape-zip and rename each shapefile component with 7zip

```
7z rn rename.zip test.shp foo.shp
7z rn rename.zip test.shx foo.shx
7z rn rename.zip test.dbf foo.dbf
7z rn rename.zip test.prj foo.prj
```

Comment: Apparently it has changed in the meantime, you can pass on the name of the shapefile in the wfs vendor options if you have a freemarker template https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/freemarker.html#tutorial-freemarkertemplate